# Is it a good practice to cache Redis data in ngx.shared

Tags: caching, nginx, lua

I have some Lua code embedded in nginx. In this code I get some small data from Redis cache. Now I wonder, if it is a good practice to cache this data (already cached in some sense) in nginx, using `ngx.shared` construct? Are there any pros and cons of doing it this way? In pseudo-code I expect to have something like:

```
local cache = ngx.shared.cache
local cached_key = cache:get("cached_key")
if cached_key == nil then
    ... get data from Redis
    cache:set("cached_key", cached_key)
end
```

Comment: I think the question is pretty vague.  A google search for "ngx.shared.cache" returns literally less than 10 results.  You'd be better asking this on the appropriate MLs.

Comment: I think, there is no sense to search for `ngx.shared.cache`, because cache in this case is my own variable name. The question is rather conceptual - in real world practice do they cache Redis (or memcached) data in nginx cache to provide more performance or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the documentation [`ngx.shared`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxshareddict) is a space shared among all the workers of the nginx server.

All the listed operations are atomic, so you only have to bother about [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) if you use two operations on `ngx.shared` one after the other. In this case, they should be protected using [`ngx.semaphore`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxsemaphore).

The pros:

- Using `ngx.shared` provides faster access to the data, because you avoid a request/response loop to the Redis server.
- Even if you need a `ngx.semaphore` you can expect faster access to the data (but i have no benchmark to provide).

The cons:

- The `ngx.shared` cache provides inaccurate data, as your local cache does not reflect the current Redis value. This is not always a crucial point, as there can always be a delta between the values used in the worker and the value stored in Redis.
- Data stored in `ngx.shared` can be inconsistent, which is more important. For instance it can store `x=true` and `y=false` whereas in Redis `x` and `y` have always the same value. It depends on how you update your local cache.
- You have to handle yourself the cache, by updating the values in your cache whenever they are sent to  Redis. This can be easily done by wrapping the redis functions. Expect bugs if you handle updates by putting it after each call to `redis.get`, because you (or someone) **will** forget it.
- You also have to handle reads: whenever a value is not found in your `ngx.cache`, you have to automatically read it from Redis. Expect bugs if you handle reads by putting them after each call to `cache.get`, because you (or someone) **will** forget it.

For the two last points, you can easily write a small wrapper module.

As a conclusion:

- If your server runs only one instance, with one or several workers, using `ngx.shared` is interesting, as you can always have a cache of your Redis data that is always up-to-date.
- If your server runs several instances and having an always up-to-date cache is mandatory, or if you could have consistency problems, then you should avoid caching using `ngx.shared`.
- In all cases, if the size of your data can be huge, make sure to provide a way to clean it before memory consumption is too high. If you cannot provide cleaning, then you should not use `ngx.shared`.

Also, do not forget to store the cached value within a `local` variable, in order to avoid `get`ing it again and again, and thus to improve efficiency.

Comment: Thank you, sir! It is very informative and helpful!